# When updating the schema in OpenLDAP, should we reload the master or the slave first?

Tags: linux, ldap, openldap

We currently have one master server that is replicated to two read-only slaves. We are adding to the schema. Is it recommended to reload the master first or the slaves?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there is some logic to the fact when you add a schema, that you restart the master first, who then propagates it to the slaves no ? I mean that's how it works in MySQL or most master/slaves configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When adding a new schema, reload the slaves first, so that they won't receive updates of unknown object-types at any time.

Otherwise if you would have to remove a schema, do it on the master first.

Comment: ...and it should go without saying, but I'll say it anyway: ***Make a backup first!***

Comment: BTW: I haven't asked if you're using slurpd or syncrepl for replication ... but it makes no difference therefore

Comment: Slurpd in my case.